# Image Scaling Issue using MDPI

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mdpi

I am creating a app using Multiple screen support. I am little confused while going through the MDPI resolutions. I came across several resolutions on MDPI. Can anyone tell me what is the exact and proper MDPI resolution needs to be used for image resizing(Scaling) in the development.

Comment: Please check this image for your reference. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV4Oh.png

Comment: This is official : http://www.androiddocs.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: Sorry Guys. Just I need MDPI Checking Resolution.

Comment: what is `MDPI Checking Resolution`?

Comment: While i'm Googleing it says " if you using Images in Multiple Screen means   change the Image Size MDPI to XXDPI. so  i dont know my MDPI Image Size that's Why Asking Genaraly MDPI Resolution?

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence also the "alternative drawables" section in https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources